# PNP search results: mention user office property from admin

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp, sharepoint-admin-center, pnp-search-webparts

I would like to mention the office instead of the current WorkPhone from the user profile (configured in admin) in my search result. How can I do this?

[image: Replace workphone property]

[image: User profile property office]